# Precision vs. accuracy of System.nanoTime()

Tags: java, nanotime

The documentation for [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) says the following (emphasis mine).

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). **This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy.** No guarantees are made about how frequently values change.

As I see it, this can be interpreted in two different ways:

1. The sentence in **bold** above refers to individual return values. Then, precision and accuracy are to be understood in the numerical sense. That is, precision refers to the number of significant digits - the position of truncation, and accuracy is whether the number is the correct one (such as described in the top answer here
   [What is the difference between 'precision' and 'accuracy'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270789/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-accuracy) )
2. The sentence in **bold** above refers to the capability of the method itself. Then, precision and accuracy are to be understood as illustrated by the dartboard analogy
   ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_vs._accuracy#Accuracy_versus_precision:_the_target_analogy ).
   So, low accuracy, high precision => the wrong value is repeatedly hit with a high precision: imagining that physical time stands still, consecutive calls of nanoTime() returns the same numerical value, but it is off from the actual elapsed time since the reference time by some *constant* offset.

Which interpretation is the correct one? My point is, interpretation 2 would mean that a measure of time *difference* using nanoTime() (by subtracting two return values) would be correct to the nanosecond (since the constant error/offset in the measurement would be eliminated), while interpretation 1 wouldn't guarantee that kind of compliance between measurements and thus wouldn't necessarily imply a high precision of time difference measurements.

---

**Updated 4/15/13:** The Java 7 documentation for [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) has been updated to address the possible confusion with the previous wording.

> Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.
>
> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary *origin* time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.
>
> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of [`currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).
>
> Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (2<sup>63</sup> nanoseconds) will not correctly compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.
>
> The values returned by this method become meaningful only when the difference between two such values, obtained within the same instance of a Java virtual machine, is computed.

Comment: As far as I know, that function depends on the possibility of the OS to return nanoseconds. So, let's say you got `x = nanoTime();` this returns you some value, let's assume `958145`. If you call `nanoTime()` exactly one nanosecond later, you're not guaranteed to get `958146`. It means it returns nanoseconds, but not necessarily the correct elapsed amount of nanoseconds between two calls.

Comment: WOW - what a well worded question to an important interesting topic!

Comment: See also [Wikipedia - False Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision).

Comment: 292 years is good to know if I wrote a software for long term space mission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first interpretation is correct. On most systems the three least-significant digits will always be zero. This in effect gives microsecond accuracy, but reports it at the fixed precision level of a nanosecond.

In fact, now that I look at it again, your second interpretation is also a valid description of what is going on, maybe even more so. Imagining freezed time, the report will be always the same wrong number of nanoseconds, but correct if understood as the integer number of microseconds.

Comment: So I should only trust a time difference measurement using nanoTime() down to the microsecond. Thanks to both answerers!

Comment: Correct - only the ABS() difference between the two values would produce anything meaningful, as is provided in some OS implementations of high-performance timers. So this function isn't about "what time is it" but rather about timers and thus comparisons of two values is what it is for (but very useful indeed).

Answer (score 12):

In Clojure command line, I get:

```
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
0
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
0
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
-641
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
0
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
-642
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
-641
user=> (- (System/nanoTime) (System/nanoTime))
-641
```

So essentially, `nanoTime` doesn't get updated every nanosecond, contrary to what one might intuitively expect from its *precision*. In Windows systems, it's using the  `QueryPerformanceCounter` API under the hood (according to [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks)), which in practice seems to give about 640 ns *resolution* (in my system!).

Note that `nanoTime` can't, by itself, have any *accuracy* at all, since its absolute value is arbitrary. Only the *difference*  between successive `nanoTime` calls is meaningful. The (in)accuracy of that difference is in the ballpark of 1 microsecond.

Comment: Excellent answer and this is true. I think the important part here is that the Java folks realized that the OS 'clock' time (from the chip and OS cache) had various problems from drift to accuracy and latency (updated only every +/- 30 ms on various systems). So this "nanoTime" implementation is really quite different - not using the clock chip but a "high performance timer" implementation, which differs at the OS level but the results are the same - timers with much more accurate resolution than the old +/- 30 ms cache/drift.

Answer (score 5):

One quite interesting feature of the difference between `System.currentTimeMillis()` & `System.nanoTime()` is that `System.nanoTime()` does NOT change with the wall clock. I run code on a Windows virtual machine that has heavy time drift. `System.currentTimeMillis()` can jump back or forward by 1-2 seconds each time as NTP corrects that drift, making accurate time stamps meaningless. (Windows 2003, 2008 VPS editions)

`System.nanoTime()` is not, however, affected by changing wall clock time so you can take a time retrieved over NTP and apply a correction based on `System.nanoTime()` since NTP was checked last and you have a far more accurate time than `System.currentTimeMillis()` in adverse wall clock conditions

This is of course counter-intuitive, but useful to know

Comment: This might explain why when running a test in java under Windows 7, Java reported a time difference of `350777 ns` (equal to 0.35 ms) using `System.getNanoTime()` , but a difference time difference of `15 ms` over the same period of time using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Looks like using `System.currentTimeMillis()` can be completely inaccurate for benchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

If someone like me comes and reads this question again and again *and again* to still kind of understand it, here is a simpler (I hope) explanation.

`Precision` is about how many digits you retain. Each of the:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long end   = System.nanoTime();
```

is going to be a precise number (lots of digits).

Since `accuracy` is measured only *compared to something*, an individual call to `System.nanoTime` makes no sense since it's value is quite arbitrary and does not depend on something that we can measure. The only way to distinguish it's accuracy is to two different calls of it, thus:

```
 long howMuch = end - start;
```

is *not* going to have a nano-second accuracy. And in fact on my machine the difference is 0.2 - 0.3 micro-seconds.