# Getting the same running time answer for different input numbers

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

So far I have done...
the first class contains Insertion Sort algorithm

```
public class Sorting {


        public static void insertionSort(int[] r)
        {
            for ( int i = 1; i < r.length; i = i+1 )
            {int v = r[i]; 
            int j = i;
            while ( j != 0 && r[j-1] > v )
            {r[j] = r[j-1];
            j = j-1;
            }
            r[j] = v;
                }
            }
}
```

and here is the second class ...

```
import java.util.*;


public class ExecutionTime{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int size=30000;
        int[] r  = new int[size];
        int number=1;
        for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
            r[i]=number;
            number++;}
        for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        System.out.println(r[i]);}
        Sorting.insertionSort(r);
         long result;
         long startTime = System.nanoTime();
         long endTime = System.nanoTime();
         result = endTime-startTime;
         System.out.println("Execution time is  " + result + " nanoseconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: when I set size=15000 and 30000 i get the same answer for both sizes...of course I have executed it many times for each size

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually timing the sorting:

```
     Sorting.insertionSort(r);
     long result;
     long startTime = System.nanoTime();
     long endTime = System.nanoTime();
     result = endTime-startTime;
```

Notice you sort first, then calculate the time difference of, well, not doing anything (there's no code between `startTime` and `endTime` are assigned). Instead, do this:

```
     long result;
     long startTime = System.nanoTime();
     Sorting.insertionSort(r);
     long endTime = System.nanoTime();
     result = endTime-startTime;
```

This way, `endTime - startTime` spans the sorting operation.

Comment: Hey...i still don't get it ...after calculating running time, i get these results:
n=7500 T(n)=6668618nanosec
 
n=15000, T(n)=10141050.6
n=30000    T(n)=10761703.9
 
n=60000   T(n)=10970219.6
 
n=120000 T(n)=18546223.2
Is it ok to have these results? I'm afraid it's not ://

Comment: Seems okay for me. What different results were you expecting?

Comment: I don't know I was totally confused after all those experiments and those different results ...
now what about when they are in the descending order...insertion sort has the worst case ...and it is n^2..n*n... so are the results I get okay? n=7500 T(n)=12523388...n=15000 T(n)=30953258...
n=30000 T(n)=98072540...n=60000 T(n)=561960091...n=120000 T(n)=1465733398

Answer (score 0):

As per [Precision vs. accuracy of System.nanoTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452597/precision-vs-accuracy-of-system-nanotime) there is no guarantee to how frequently the values it returns will change. Just because 4000 nanoseconds have passed between two times you've called the function does not mean the value has changed.

Precision vs. accuracy at work.