# Assign a value to a variable for a limited time only

Tags: scala

Let's say that there is a boolean variable, initially assigned the value `false`. Is there a way to say, let this variable be `true` for the next 5 minutes and then let it be `false` again?

My current idea is that I could store the variable along with a timestamp, then as soon as the variable is turned to `true`, the timestamp is set to the current time, then check the variable's value through a method that will return `true` if the current time and the initial timestamp form a duration of less than 5 minutes and then `false` if the duration is greater than 5 minutes. I'm thinking about an implicit conversion from `Boolean` to a `RichBoolean` that would handle this mechanism through an elegant method name or something.

Is there a more elegant or Scala native way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp idea is pretty easy to implement (here the argument is in seconds):

```
class TransientlyTrue(duration: Double) {
  private[this] val createdAt = System.nanoTime
  def value = (System.nanoTime-createdAt)*1e-9 <= duration
}
implicit def TransientToBoolean(t: TransientlyTrue) = t.value
```

With the implicit conversion you can transparently drop this in wherever you need a `Boolean`.  Or you could leave that off and just call `.value`.

Comment: Yeah, so it apparently doesn't get "eleganter". Thanks anyway.

Comment: I always wonder why anybody defaults to nanoTime, rather than to milliseconds, especially given that [nanos may be not accurate enough](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11452597/298389) and harder for humans. What is the reason behind such choose?

Comment: nanoTime uses a high-resolution date/time independent clock. currentTimeMillis uses the system clock - so if someone resets the date,  your timing tends to get messed up.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to accomplish what you want more elegantly with futures. You won't have a proper variable that's changing its value, but it's not clear that that's an absolute requirement in your question, and you will have a method that starts returning a different value after a certain amount of time. For example, with [Twitter's implementation](https://github.com/twitter/util):

```
import com.twitter.util._
import com.twitter.conversions.time._

implicit val timer = new JavaTimer

val t = Future.sleep(10.seconds)
```

Now `t.isDone` will be false for ten seconds and then true. The nice thing about this approach is that you get lots of other combinators on the future that may allow you to solve your problem more directly—see [the Scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) for more information.

Comment: Note of course that you could also have your future change the value of a `var` when it completes, but I feel like there _must_ be a better way to solve your problem than that.

Answer (score -1):

Would you be okay with a wrapper object for this? Like TimedBoolean? If so, then you could do something pretty straight forward with either a Timer, or just on your getter and setter do a timestamp check..

To **directly** answer your question, though, no, there's no Scala native way of doing this. But I'd think that a wrapper method is the "more elegant" way you're looking for.