# Why 60.5 - 60.1 is 0.399999999999999 ? In C# double variable

Tags: c#

```
double a=60.5;
double a=60.1;

Console.WriteLine(a-b);
```

> Return value is 0.399999999999999 not 0.4

Comment: Is there some reason why the seven and a half million *other* questions on SO about floating point imprecision didn't satisfy your curiosity? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm guessing there were actually only 7499999 other questions and this was the one missing...

Comment: Have a look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Answer (score 3):

It is because you use double: double is floating point, which is not precise; decimal, on the other hand, is precise. If you change both variable to decimal, it will be the exact number.

That is why in certain domains, like financial industry, decimal is desired for accuracy and precision.

Comment: This is not accurate. `Decimal` is floating-point too. The big difference is that `float` is base-2 and thus can only approximate base-10 numbers, while `Decimal` is base-10 which removes any errors due to simple approximation. It is still vulnerable to precision errors if used unwisely.

Comment: Doubles *are* precise in that they have precision. What they *don't* have is infinite precision. Something else that doesn't have infinite precision is Decimals :-) No encoding method (other than actual symbolics) can handle all cases, such as `√2`, `π`, `e`, or `⅓` - these will all cause precision loss for Decimal type. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270789/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-accuracy/8270869#8270869.