# What's the C++ suffix for long double literals?

Tags: c++, c, literals, floating-point-precision

In C++ (and C), a floating point literal without suffix defaults to `double`, while the suffix `f` implies a `float`. But what is the suffix to get a `long double`?

Without knowing, I would define, say,

```
const long double x = 3.14159265358979323846264338328;
```

But my worry is that the variable `x` contains fewer significant bits of `3.14159265358979323846264338328` than 64, because this is a `double` literal. Is this worry justified?

Comment: Just preprocess this file `#include <float.h> LDBL_MAX` and you see `1.18973149535723176502e+4932L` which answers your question.

Comment: As to the question "is this worry justified" it really depends. Your PI value has a precision of 1e-28. Machine epsilon for double is ~2.22e-16, so it IS smaller than what you are looking for to capture this number precisely. Does it matter? Depends on whether or not you need to be that precise in your calculations...

Comment: @EricPostpischil it obviously shows how to spell out a `long double` constant... (suffix L)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From the C++ Standard

> The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified
>   by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L
>   specify long double.

It is interesting to compare with corresponding paragraph of the C Standard. In C there is used term  `floating constant` instead of `floating literal` in C++:

> 4 An unsuffixed floating constant has type double. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double

Answer (score 28):

The C suffix is `L`. I'd strongly suspect that it is the same for C++.

Your worry is justified. Your literal would first be converted to a `double`, and thus truncated, and then converted back to `long double`.

Answer (score 13):

Your concern is valid and you should use a `L` suffix for long double literal.

Comment: Where does the `F` come from? I checked the C standard, and there it only is `L`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the `l` suffix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float t1 = 1.10000000000000000002l;
  double t2 = 1.10000000000000000002l;
  long double t3 = 1.10000000000000000002L;
  cout << setprecision(25);
  cout << t1 << endl;
  cout << t2 << endl;
  cout << t3 << endl;
}
```

Still I get this output indicating the lack of desired precision:

```
1.10000002384185791015625
1.100000000000000088817842
1.100000000000000088817842
```

Comment: With many implementations, the representations (and thus value range, precision etc.) of `double` and `long double` are identical (e.g. 64 bit IEEE float). Just like on many implementations, the representations of `long` and `long long` are identical (e.g. 64 bit 2's complement signed integer). In both cases though, they are still treated as different by the type system. E.g. calling a function template with `1.0` and `1.0L` will deduce different types and call different specializations of the template. Same with `1L` and `1LL`.