# How to convert a double to long double in C++ style?

Tags: c++

In C++, we can use 1ll to convert a number to `long long` type. Is there a similar way to convert to `long double` type in C++? If so, what should I multiply the number by? Thank you!

I've tried `1.0f`, but that's not what I'm looking for because it lacks precision.

Comment: The type of `1.0f` is `float`, so it's definitely not what you're looking for. Use `l` or `L` for `long double`.

Comment: `1ll` is not a conversion. `1.0f` is for `float`, not `long double`. `long double` has many issues, and you should probably not use it without understanding what they are.

Comment: Why not simply initialize or assign to a `long double` variable? Also note that C++ doesn't guarantee that `long double` actually have more precision than `double`. On some common systems `long double` is exactly the same as `double`. Also, if you need larger numbers, or greater precision than `double` gives you, I rather recommend some arbitrary precision library instead.

Comment: Most likely this is a duplicate of this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557816/whats-the-c-suffix-for-long-double-literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557816/whats-the-c-suffix-for-long-double-literals)

Comment: @drescherjm Hard to say, OP seems terribly confused.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I didn't vote close as duplicate which I would usually do.

Comment: @drescherjm nevermind, OP wants exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, to convert a number to long double type, you can simply append an "L" or "l" to the number. This tells the compiler to treat the number as a long double. Here's how you can do it:

```
long double myNumber = 1.0L;
```

By appending "L" or "l" to the number, you ensure that it's interpreted as a long double literal rather than a double or float. This allows you to maintain precision in calculations involving long double values.

Comment: Is this answer generated with AI?